# "Translating" a strange pseudocode into python

Tags: pseudocode

I'm doing an assignment and in one of the questions, my professor put some strange pseudo code as a condition and frankly I'm not sure if I understood it correctly.

This is what he gave us:

```
LOOP if S>0 then {S:=S-1; exit} end_if;
END_LOOP
```

can I understand this as

```
while True:
    if S>0:
        S = S - 1
        break
```

if I were to rewrite it in Python?

Or, should it be like this?

```
while S>0:
    S = S -1
    break
```

Answer (score -2):

It's not 100% clear, but given that the first version will either go around once, or go around forever, it's likely to be the second one.